# how do I copy an object containing collections as fields

Tags: java, object, collections, copy

consider the below code:

```
public class Bid {

private double pe;

private List<ResChar> resourceList;


protected Map<Integer,Integer>scheduleOfSeller ;

public Map<Integer, Integer> getScheduleOfSeller() {
    return scheduleOfSeller;
}

public void setScheduleOfSeller(Map<Integer, Integer> scheduleOfSeller) {
    this.scheduleOfSeller = scheduleOfSeller;
}


private int bidId;

public int getBidId() {
    return bidId;
}

public void setBidId(int bidId) {
    this.bidId = bidId;
}

public double getPe() {
    return pe;
}

public void setPe(double pe) {
    this.pe = pe;
}

public List<ResChar> getResourceList() {
    return resourceList;
}

public void setResourceList(List<ResChar> resourceList) {
    this.resourceList = resourceList;
}


public Bid(int bidId,double pe, List<ResChar> resourceList){
    setBidId(bidId);
    setPe(pe);
    setResourceList(resourceList);
    this.scheduleOfSeller = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
}

}
```

I want to make a copy constructor of the bid like this :

```
public class BidCopy{

public Bid bid;

public BidCopy(Bid bidBuyer){
    List<ResChar> resList = new LinkedList<ResChar>(); 
    for (ResChar elt : bidBuyer.getResourceList()){
        ResCharCopy eltCopy = new ResCharCopy(elt);
        resList.add(eltCopy.elt);
    }
    this.bid = bidBuyer;
    this.bid.setResourceList(resList);
}

}
```

The only solution that I know to make such copy is to proceed like follows :

```
public class BidCopy{

public Bid copy;

public BidCopy(Bid bid){
    List<ResChar> resList = new LinkedList<ResChar>(); 
    for (ResChar elt : bid.getResourceList()){
        ResCharCopy eltCopy = new ResCharCopy(elt);
        resList.add(eltCopy.elt);
    }
    this.copy = new Bid(bid.getBidId(), bid.getPe(), resList);
}

}
```

So I want to know if there is any other solution to make a copy of "Bid" Object more effectively ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest making a copy constructor for your Bid object (and not a specific class for copying), a Bid is made out of its fields and not methods, like so:

```
public class Bid {
int ID;
String description;
Object bidStuff;

// ...as before

public Bid(Bid bid) {
    this.ID = bid.ID;
    this.description = bid.description;
    this.bidStuff = bid.bidStuff;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Bid> original = new ArrayList<>();
    // ..populate it
    List<Bid> copy = new ArrayList<>(original.size());

    for (Bid b : original) {
        copy.add(new Bid(b));
    }
}
}
```

You can even make the copy constructor protected or package-protected if you don't want anyone else to mess around with making multiple copies of bids.

Answer (score 0):

There is not. Even though some collections have "copy constructors", these constructors will copy the elements' references, they will not create new elements for you.

You can however "optimize" the list creation itself by submitting the size of the initial list to the constructor:

```
List<X> newList = new LinkedList<X>(oldList.size());
```